# How do validators know a policy script is expired based only on slot number?

Tags: policy

A policy script can be set to expire. For example:

```
{ 
  "before": 51000000
}
```

The number corresponds to a slot number within the epoch the script is being created. However, the current slot number will be below that number again in subsequent epochs (since slot number starts at 0 each epoch and counts up). How does a validator know that the policy script is expired when it only contains slot information but not epoch information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slot number does not get reset with each epoch. You can see here that the slot number is strictly increasing: https://explorer.cardano.org/en.html